# Style width:100%;height:100% is not working in IE6.0

Tags: css

```
#backgroundPopup{
position:absolute;
height:100%;
width:100%;
}
```

its fine, if we give width=500px; but when we put as % then no result. In IE6.0 Why?

Comment: I'd recommend http://doctype.com/ for this kind of question.

Comment: they don't respond fast as SO does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting this in addition

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```